GitLab web service not connecting to the registry
On an on-prem GitLab server hosted on Kubernetes, after an upgrade of GitLab to the latest version 17.1.0, I notice that the webservice fails to connect to the registry service:
{"component": "gitlab","subcomponent":"exceptions_json","severity":"ERROR","time":"2024-06-23T19:24:45.983Z","correlation_id":"01J14RZ0P76QJCW9CBD0XHAY23","meta.caller_id":"Projects::Registry::RepositoriesController#index","meta.remote_ip":"10.42.3.47","meta.feature_category":"container_registry","meta.user":"paul","meta.user_id":2,"meta.project":"personal/my-project","meta.root_namespace":"personal","meta.client_id":"user/2","exception.class":"Faraday::ConnectionFailed","exception.message":"Failed to open TCP connection to gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000 (execution expired)","exception.backtrace":["gems/gitlab-http/lib/net_http/connect_patch.rb:52:in `initialize'","gems/gitlab-http/lib/net_http/connect_patch.rb:52:in `open'","gems/gitlab-http/lib/net_http/connect_patch.rb:52:in `block in connect'","timeout (0.3.2) lib/timeout.rb:189:in `block in timeout'","timeout (0.3.2) lib/timeout.rb:196:in `timeout'","gems/gitlab-http/lib/net_http/connect_patch.rb:50:in `connect'","net-http (0.4.1) lib/net/http.rb:1580:in `do_start'","net-http (0.4.1) lib/net/http.rb:1569:in `start'","faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:138:in `request_via_get_method'","faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:129:in `request_with_wrapped_block'","faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:122:in `perform_request'","faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:66:in `block in call'","faraday (1.10.0) lib/faraday/adapter.rb:50:in `connection'","faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:64:in `call'","lib/gitlab/faraday/error_callback.rb:30:in `call'","faraday-retry (1.0.3) lib/faraday/retry/middleware.rb:140:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/response_middleware.rb:36:in `call'","faraday (1.10.0) lib/faraday/middleware.rb:18:in `call'","faraday_middleware (1.2.0) lib/faraday_middleware/request/encode_json.rb:26:in `call'","faraday (1.10.0) lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:154:in `build_response'","faraday (1.10.0) lib/faraday/connection.rb:516:in `run_request'","faraday (1.10.0) lib/faraday/connection.rb:200:in `get'","lib/container_registry/client.rb:45:in `registry_info'","lib/container_registry/client.rb:40:in `block in registry_info'","lib/container_registry/base_client.rb:44:in `with_dummy_client'","lib/container_registry/client.rb:39:in `registry_info'","app/controllers/concerns/registry/connection_errors_handler.rb:35:in `ping_container_registry'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:400:in `block in make_lambda'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block (2 levels) in halting'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in \u003cmodule:Callbacks\u003e'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:200:in `block in halting'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `block in invoke_before'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `each'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:595:in `invoke_before'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:116:in `block in run_callbacks'","app/controllers/application_controller.rb:468:in `set_current_admin'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'","app/controllers/application_controller.rb:459:in `set_session_storage'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:114:in `with_locale'","lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:120:in `with_user_locale'","app/controllers/application_controller.rb:450:in `set_locale'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","marginalia (1.11.1) lib/marginalia.rb:109:in `record_query_comment'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","app/controllers/application_controller.rb:443:in `set_current_context'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","sentry-rails (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rails/controller_transaction.rb:28:in `block in sentry_around_action'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/hub.rb:102:in `with_child_span'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:490:in `with_child_span'","sentry-rails (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rails/controller_transaction.rb:14:in `sentry_around_action'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:233:in `process_action'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:23:in `process_action'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:67:in `block in process_action'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:66:in `process_action'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:259:in `process_action'","activerecord (7.0.8.4) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:27:in `process_action'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:151:in `process'","actionview (7.0.8.4) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:39:in `process'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:188:in `dispatch'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:251:in `dispatch'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:18:in `block in \u003cclass:Constraints\u003e'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:48:in `serve'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:50:in `block in serve'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `each'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:852:in `call'","gitlab-experiment (0.9.1) lib/gitlab/experiment/middleware.rb:19:in `call'","omniauth (2.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:202:in `call!'","omniauth (2.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'","flipper (0.26.2) lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:72:in `memoized_call'","flipper (0.26.2) lib/flipper/middleware/memoizer.rb:37:in `call'","lib/gitlab/metrics/elasticsearch_rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_shard_awareness_validation.rb:20:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/sidekiq_sharding/validator.rb:42:in `enabled'","lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_shard_awareness_validation.rb:20:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/memory_report.rb:13:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/speedscope.rb:13:in `call'","lib/gitlab/database/load_balancing/rack_middleware.rb:23:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/rails_queue_duration.rb:33:in `call'","lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:21:in `call'","lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/metrics/web_transaction.rb:46:in `run'","lib/gitlab/metrics/rack_middleware.rb:16:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `block in call'","lib/gitlab/database/query_analyzer.rb:40:in `within'","lib/gitlab/middleware/query_analyzer.rb:11:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/organizations/current.rb:20:in `call'","batch-loader (2.0.5) lib/batch_loader/middleware.rb:11:in `call'","rack-attack (6.7.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:103:in `call'","apollo_upload_server (2.1.6) lib/apollo_upload_server/middleware.rb:19:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:173:in `call'","rack-attack (6.7.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:127:in `call'","warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:36:in `block in call'","warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'","warden (1.2.9) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'","rack-cors (2.0.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:102:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:38:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:36:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:50:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/unauthenticated_session_expiry.rb:18:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:704:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/same_site_cookies.rb:27:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'","sentry-rails (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rails/rescued_exception_interceptor.rb:12:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/path_traversal_check.rb:27:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_malformed_strings.rb:21:in `call'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in call'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/hub.rb:251:in `with_session_tracking'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:403:in `with_session_tracking'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:20:in `block in call'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/hub.rb:59:in `with_scope'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry-ruby.rb:383:in `with_scope'","sentry-ruby (5.17.3) lib/sentry/rack/capture_exceptions.rb:19:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'","lograge (0.11.2) lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call_app'","railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'","activesupport (7.0.8.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'","railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/handle_ip_spoof_attack_error.rb:25:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/request_context.rb:15:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/webhook_recursion_detection.rb:15:in `call'","request_store (1.5.1) lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'","rack-timeout (0.6.3) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:148:in `block in call'","rack-timeout (0.6.3) lib/rack/timeout/support/timeout.rb:19:in `timeout'","rack-timeout (0.6.3) lib/rack/timeout/core.rb:147:in `call'","config/initializers/fix_local_cache_middleware.rb:11:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/compressed_json.rb:44:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/rack_multipart_tempfile_factory.rb:19:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'","lib/gitlab/middleware/sidekiq_web_static.rb:20:in `call'","lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:79:in `call'","gitlab-labkit (0.36.0) lib/labkit/middleware/rack.rb:22:in `block in call'","gitlab-labkit (0.36.0) lib/labkit/context.rb:35:in `with_context'","gitlab-labkit (0.36.0) lib/labkit/middleware/rack.rb:21:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'","actionpack (7.0.8.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:131:in `call'","railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'","railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `public_send'","railties (7.0.8.4) lib/rails/railtie.rb:226:in `method_missing'","lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:13:in `call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:74:in `block in call'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `each'","rack (2.2.8.1) lib/rack/urlmap.rb:58:in `call'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/configuration.rb:272:in `call'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:100:in `block in handle_request'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:378:in `with_force_shutdown'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/request.rb:99:in `handle_request'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/server.rb:241:in `block in run'","puma (6.4.0) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:155:in `block in spawn_thread'"],"exception.cause_class":"Net::OpenTimeout","user.username":"paul","tags.program":"web","tags.locale":"en","tags.feature_category":"container_registry","tags.correlation_id":"01J14RZ0P76QJCW9CBD0XHAY23","extra.class":"ContainerRegistry::BaseClient","extra.url":"http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000/v2/"}

From the gitlab-runner pod, I can resolve the hostname and I can also cURL the URL from the error above.
gitlab-gitlab-runner-5dff88bf84-b7hpg:/$ curl -v http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000
* Host gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 10.43.168.151
*   Trying 10.43.168.151:5000...
* Connected to gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local (10.43.168.151) port 5000
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000
> User-Agent: curl/8.5.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2024 11:27:52 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local left intact

Also from the web service pod I can reach the port 5000 with cURL:
git@gitlab-webservice-default-695d898db4-6gtk4:/$ curl -v http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000
*   Trying 10.43.168.151:5000...
* Connected to gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local (10.43.168.151) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.88.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Thu, 27 Jun 2024 11:30:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local left intact

I can also reach the service if I forward the port or access it through a reverse proxy. There are no network policies configured.
I have changed the config map for the web service to update the url from http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc:5000 to http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000 as the first hostname was not being resolved by the runner pod.
The service exists, the namespace is gitlab, I don't see any connection attempts in the registry pod logs from the web service.

So, you are able to reach http://gitlab-registry.gitlab.svc.cluster.local:5000/ using curl? Including port 5000?

@C-nan I have updated the question with the cURL outputs from both web service and runner pods, they both reach the registry service just fine. It's just that gitlab application fails to reach it for some reason.

Somehow this got fixed by updating Gitlab to v17.3.0.
